# None of the NPM commands are working, it is the same error "ENOTSUP". Tried pretty much everything that has been suggested in here

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-package

All the npm commands show the same error.

```
> npm install

npm ERR! code ENOTSUP

npm ERR! syscall link

npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\cc663e0b
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\69\67\ 
 218d03e13d2c81f50304b0a52655ac49c51a83e8f6d4a85d84216d0b6b1ebd2607c545f 
 a9df6373be1c0a88091f02b06f26eddbff4e9ab17bf629168a497

npm ERR! errno ENOTSUP

npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch  
 https://registry.npmjs.org/autoprefixer: ENOTSUP: operation not  
 supported on socket,link 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm- 
 cache\_cacache\tmp\cc663e0b' -> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm- 
 cache\_cacache\content- 
 v2\sha512\69\67\218d03e13d2c81f50304b0a52655ac49c51a83e8f6d4a85d84216d0   
 b6b1ebd2607c545fa9df6373be1c0a88091f02b06f26eddbff4e9ab17bf629168a497'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03- 
 24T05_30_08_656Z-debug-0.log
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs with the latest and LTS versions multiple times. NPM cache clean --force command is also not working, I deleted the npm-cache folder from ~/Appdata but still the error is recurring.

npm cache clean --force didn't work

```
>npm cache clean --force

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
```

npm cache verify didn't work.

Comment: Can you reach https://registry.npmjs.org/autoprefixer in your browser? I'm wondering whether some firewall or other infrastructure prevents access.

Comment: I checked it, am able to access the link

Comment: Thank you, it was an antivirus issue, the error got resolved after I uninstalled the antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Run **npm install --legacy-peer-deps**

Comment: Still has the same error as the rest of the commands

Comment: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/npm-install-not-working.html                                                go through this link and try

Comment: Thnks you, the issue got resolved after I uninstalled the antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `--no-bin-links` to the command end.

E.g:
`npm install pkg --no-bin-links`

GitHub [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7938)

Comment: I did this once before, it showed the same error. I checked it  now just in case still shows the same error.

Comment: trying using another package manager like yarn, pnpm

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the error got resolved after I uninstalled my antivirus.